# Django MPTT. Ссылка для каждой ветки дерева

Tags: python, ubuntu, django

С помощью django-mptt создал древовидное меню:

```
<pre>
Галерея
--Фото птичек
----Совы
----Воробьи
--Фото машин
----bmw
----2106
и т.д
</pre>
```

Вопрос: как теперь мне присвоить ссылку для перехода на конкретную страницу, например на bmw ?
В документации предлагают это:

```
<pre>
{% load mptt_tags %}
<ul>
    {% recursetree nodes %}
        <li>
            {{ node.name }}
            {% if not node.is_leaf_node %}
                <ul class="children">
                    {{ children }}
                </ul>
            {% endif %}
        </li>
    {% endrecursetree %}
</ul>
</pre>
```

Но тег `<a>` не работает - `<a href="#">{{children}}</a>`

Comment: На сайте используется разметка Markdown, не стесняйтесь её использовать при оформлении вопросов, особенно кода. Подробнее: http://ru.stackoverflow.com/editing-help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Не там ссылку ставите

```
{% load mptt_tags %}
<ul>
    {% recursetree nodes %}
        <li>
            <a href="{{ node.get_absolute_url }}">{{ node.name }}</a>
            {% if not node.is_leaf_node %}
                <ul class="children">
                    {{ children }}
                </ul>
            {% endif %}
        </li>
    {% endrecursetree %}
</ul>
```